# Get data from server with URLSession

Tags: json, swiftui, decodable, urlsession

everyone. I have a problem. I can't figure out. I want get data ( JSON array ) from my server, it doesn't work correctly. It doesn't show nothing. HTTP header: text/plain . I use this source as example: https://medium.com/@rbreve/displaying-a-list-with-swiftui-from-a-remote-json-file-6b4e4280a076 . It's my code and data:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Medewerker: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    public var id : Int
    public var naam: String
    public var voornaam: String              
}
struct SwiftUIView2: View {
       @ObservedObject var fetcher = MedewerkerFetcher()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetcher.medewerker) { medewerker in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(medewerker.naam)
                    Text(medewerker.voornaam)
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

struct SwiftUIView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView2()
    }
}
public class MedewerkerFetcher: ObservableObject {

    @Published var medewerker = [Medewerker]()

    init(){
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://anwin.be/src/public/medewerker")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data,response,error) in
            if let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType == "text/plain"{
                do {
                    if let d = data {
                        let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Medewerker].self, from: d)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.medewerker = decodedLists
                        }
                    }else {
                        print("No Data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print ("Error")
                }
           } 

        }.resume()

    }
}
```

```
Data. Json from server:
```

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "naam": "Fanoberov",
        "voornaam": "Andre"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "naam": "Kunitski",
        "voornaam": "Dzmitry"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "naam": "Karim",
        "voornaam": "Nassar"
    }
]
```

Can you help me, please ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error is:

`{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dtcws.azurewebsites.net/ShowImg.aspx?params=dtc_376_0_True_False_22, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.})`

you have to change your info.plist
add this:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```